# Precision of APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_count_distinct) , it says that the function returns the approximate result for COUNT(DISTINCT expression). However, I would like to know what's the variance of the result from using APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT compared to COUNT(DISTINCT expression). I have looked this up in the documentation and haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Related to this article: https://developers.google.com/analytics/blog/2022/hll

APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT variance may vary - each time it is used.

On the other hand, using HLL+ sketch allows you to configure how accurate the estimation will be.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).